# Python IDLE doesn't find text files unless I specify the path

Tags: python, file

In my Python books and also the Python Documents this code should be enough to open a file:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
```

But if I do this I will get an error message telling me file.txt doesn't exist. If I however use the whole path where file.txt is located it opens it:

```
 f = open("C:/Users/Me/Python/file.txt", "r")
```

Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - the immediate search path (the current working directory) is where Python will look... (so on Windows - possibly it'll assume C:\Pythonxy)

Yes, it depends on where Python/IDLE is executed... for it to use its search path:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/jon'

>>> open('testing.txt')
<open file 'testing.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f86e140edb0>
```

And in a shell - changing directories... then launching Python/IDLE

```
jon@forseti:~$ cd /srv
jon@forseti:/srv$ idle

>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/srv'
>>> open('testing.txt')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    open('testing.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testing.txt'
```

Comment: When I typed your code I got:
    
                       >>>C:\\Python33

Does this mean I have to save my files in this directory to not have to declare the whole path for every file I want to open from now on?

Comment: @SingSandibar Run them from the directory they're in - `cd` into them, and run them there...